# Blade Custom Directive receives value as a string instead of its original value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm newbie in Laravel, researched but i can't find a solution for something so simple. I created a custom directive namely "test" for Blade in the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('test', function($expression){
            // Dumps as well: "$var1 , $var2"
            dump($expression);

            list($arg1, $arg2) = explode(',',str_replace(['(',')',' '], '', $expression));

            // will print: $var1 , $var2
            return "<?php echo '$arg1 , $arg2'; ?>";
        }); 
    }

    /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Theoretically, its usage should be very simple inside a blade template, however as shown in the following example the directive is printing the literal value of the arguments e.g $var1 is printing $var1 instead of its real content "test a":

```
<?php 
    $var1 = 'test a'; 
    $var2 = 'test b'; 
?>

// Prints: $var1 , $var2
// Expected: "test a test b"
@test($var1 , $var2)
```

Already tried to print their values using multiple tags:

```
@test( {{ $var1  }}, {{ $var2  }})
@test( {!! $var1 !!}, {!! $var2 !!})
@test( {{{ $var1 }}}, {{{ $var2 }}})
```

But doesn't work neither, the directive is always receiving the name of the variable instead of its content. What am I ignoring in this case? Any help is appreciated. I am using Laravel 5.4.*.

Comment: Change the return to `return "<?php echo $arg1 . ' ' . $arg2; ?>";`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Finally I have the  real solution.

You need to add the line starts with list to return statement because blade creates a php file in storage/framework/views directory after replacing directives. So you need something like the followings.

```
Blade::directive('test', function($expression){
    return
       '<?php
           list($arg1, $arg2) = explode(\',\',str_replace([\'(\',\')\',\' \'], \'\', ' . $expression . '));
           echo "$arg1 -- $arg2";
       ?>';
});
```

Finally you can use it like followings;

```
@php($expression = "(0,1)")
@test($expression)
@test("(10,12)") //It works now
```

Note: you should create BladeServiceProvider in Providers directory then you should add it to providers in config/app.php. Then you can add your directive to BladeServiceProvider. It is not important. It is just more proper way than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, after you have done making your custom blade:

`php artisan view:clear`.